# How to render PDF using pdf.js viewer in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qtwebkit, pdf.js, qtwebengine

I have tried adding the pdf.js viewer files in my project and it works in browsers like Chrome, Mozilla, Safari, etc, but it's not loading some pages in node-webkit and PyQt webkit.

I am trying to load the file using an iframe, like this:

```html
<iframe src="/test/?file=/assets/pdf/example.pdf#page=3"> </iframe>
```

Comment: Showing your relevant code is generally strongly preferred.

Comment: crosspost https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/4715

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[I've found this thread over at the Qt Forums](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/41678/#179365), where thebeast44 posted a snippet of Qt code answering your question. My translation to python is below.

You'll also need to unpack the res folder from the [author's original code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hd2hdeeipu6ju9y/pdftest.zip), I think he just modified the viewer... I've also attached said code [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2352081/pdf_test_res.zip).

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtNetwork
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit


class PDFViewer(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    pdf_viewer_page = 'res/pdf-viewer.html'

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.settings = QtWebKit.QWebSettings.globalSettings()
        self.settings.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, True )
        self.settings.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, True )
        self.settings.setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.DeveloperExtrasEnabled, True )
        nam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
        page = QtWebKit.QWebPage(self)
        page.setNetworkAccessManager(nam)
        self.setPage(page)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.onLoadFinish)
        self.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl(self.pdf_viewer_page))

    def onLoadFinish(self, success):
        if success:
            self.page().mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript("init();")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    viewer = PDFViewer(parent=None)
    viewer.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you So much @fstafforini . i works in node-webkit also in qtpy thanks you so much .

Answer (score 9):

Below are some more up-to-date demo scripts for using [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) with PyQt4/QtWebKit or PyQt5/QtWebEngine. To try these, first [download the latest stable version of pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download) and unpack the zip file into a suitable location. (NB: if you're on Linux your distro may already have a pdf.js package, so that could be installed instead).

**UPDATE**:

As of Qt-5.13.0, it is also possible to use the [built-in Chromium PDF Viewer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#pdf-file-viewing) with QWebEngineView:

[image: screenshot]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

PDF = 'file://path/to/my/sample.pdf'

class Window(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.settings().setAttribute(
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)
        self.settings().setAttribute(
            QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineSettings.PdfViewerEnabled, True)
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput(PDF))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 50, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

PyQt5/QtWebEngine *pdfjs* script:

**UPDATE**:

NB: as of Aug 2022, it may be necessary to use the legacy build of pdfjs (i.e. the build for "older browsers" on the [download page](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download)) to keep things working with PyQt5. The stable build should work okay with PyQt6, though.

[image: screenshot]

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

PDFJS = 'file:///path/to/pdfjs-1.9.426-dist/web/viewer.html'
# PDFJS = 'file:///usr/share/pdf.js/web/viewer.html'
PDF = 'file:///path/to/my/sample.pdf'

class Window(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput('%s?file=%s' % (PDFJS, PDF)))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 50, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

PyQt4/QtWebKit *pdfjs* script:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

PDFJS = 'file:///path/to/pdfjs-1.9.426-dist/web/viewer.html'
# PDFJS = 'file:///usr/share/pdf.js/web/viewer.html'
PDF = 'file:///path/to/my/sample.pdf'

class Window(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput('%s?file=%s' % (PDFJS, PDF)))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 50, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: When I run the PyQt5/QtWebEngine script, I see "0 of 0" and "automatic zoom" in the menu bar but the display area is empty. The following error is displayed in the console: js: Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: globalThis is not defined. I am running the most recent anaconda packages (python 3.8, qt 5.9.7, pyqt 5.9.2) on Ubuntu 20.04. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2514157 I just tested the script in my answer using pdfjs-2.6.347 with qt 5.15.2 and pyqt 5.15.2 and it works fine for me on linux. Does ubuntu have a pdfjs package? If it does, you should use that, otherwise there may be version incompatibilities.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I did not realize it was necessary to install PyQtWebEngine in addition to Qt and PyQt5. Fixed with "pip install PyQtWebEngine".

Comment: When I try the PyQt5/QtWebEngine script I get the error message js: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . js: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?
The viewer controls are visible but the content remains blank.
I'm using python 3.7 / windows 10 / pyqtwebengine 5.12.1 / pyqt 5.12.3. Any Ideas?

Comment: @dukeeloo Works fine for me using qt-5.15.2 and pdfjs-2.11.388 on linux. You could also use the built-in chromium pdf viewer if you can upgrade to qt-5.13.x or greater. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for adding this. I'm using conda and am stuck with pyqt5<5.13 for now. (see https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/12829) Independent of this I don't see why your PyQt5/QtWebEngine pdfjs script would not work in my installation.

Comment: @dukeeloo Well, obviously there's a version compatibility issue. If you insist on using outdated software like conda, it's inevitable this will happen sooner or later. Which version of `pdfjs` are you using? Have tried all four of the [current prebuilds](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download)? If none of those work, you could [try building one of the earlier releases](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). Of course, it could also be due to a bug in your version of qt/webengine, in which case I don't see any obvious solution (other than ditching conda, that is).

Comment: @dukeeloo The [latest version of qt-5.12 (LTS)](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_5.12_Release) is 5.12.12. Are you at least able to upgrade to that? (NB: official support for qt-5.12 ends on 5th Dec 2021, so there won't be any more patch releases).

Comment: @ekhumoro I only tried with the latest version pdfjs-2.10.377. pyqt 5.12.12 is not on conda-forge yet. I know I should change to pip and I will if there is one more issue. For now I can live without this feature and hope conda will be updated very soon. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

From PyQt5 v5.13 you can load PDF files with the chromium API. According to the documentation https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#pdf-file-viewing this option is by default enabled.

This minimal example is adapted from [Simple Browser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-simplebrowser-example.html)

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5 import QAxContainer
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QApplication


class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.qlineedit = QLineEdit()
        self.qlineedit.returnPressed.connect(self.go_action)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.qlineedit)
        self.read_btn = QPushButton('Test')
        self.read_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_action)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.read_btn)

        self.WebBrowser = QAxContainer.QAxWidget(self)
        self.WebBrowser.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.WebBrowser.setControl("{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2}")
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.WebBrowser)

    def go_action(self):
        # convert system path to web path
        f = Path(self.qlineedit.text()).as_uri()
        # load object 
        self.WebBrowser.dynamicCall('Navigate(const QString&)', f)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

This example:

[image: This example]

Comment: QAxContainer is Windows specific according to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxcontainer-module.html. Is there another option for Linux users?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(