# Problem with displaying PDF in in window using PySide2 in Maya 2020

Tags: maya, pyside2

guys. I am a little bit stuck. I looked up a lot of examples about how to set up your pdf file inside the widget, but it's a little bit tricky in Maya. Here is the code that I took from google and edited a little bit for myself:

```
from PySide2 import QtWebEngineWidgets, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    self.setWindowTitle("PDF Viewer")
    self.setGeometry(0, 28, 1000, 750)

    self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    self.webView.settings().setAttribute(self.webView.settings().WebAttribute.PluginsEnabled, True)
    #self.webView.settings().setAttribute(self.webView.settings().WebAttribute.PdfViewerEnabled, True)
    self.setCentralWidget(self.webView)

def url_changed(self):
    self.setWindowTitle(self.webView.title())

def go_back(self):
    self.webView.back()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    window.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("file:///C:/Users/test/test/Document.pdf"))
```

If I try to make run it right now, I will get a white window, I guess it is because  `#self.webView.settings().setAttribute(self.webView.settings().WebAttribute.PdfViewerEnabled, True)` this line is commented out. Problem is Maya's PySide2 doesn't see `PdfViewerEnabled` existing inside WebAttributes. Again, my guess is that PySide2 inside Maya 2020 is below 5.13 qt version, where pdfviewer was introduced. Can somebody advice me how to make pdf reader work inside Maya ? Thank you.

Comment: Use an external javascript reader, like PDF.js.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render PDF using pdf.js viewer in PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23389001/how-to-render-pdf-using-pdf-js-viewer-in-pyqt)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, No, the answer there uses PdfViewerEnabled and it doesn't work in Maya.